# Прозрачный статусбар

Tags: android

Можно ли сделать полностью прозрачный статусбар в android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

Comment: Этот вариант мне больше подходил, но на устройстве Mi 9T, почему-то тулбар смешался к статусбару и немного его перекрывал, статусбар становился прозрачным. В итоге из-за смещения решил отказаться от этого способа. Не знаю может быть проблема связана с конкретной моделью устройства.

Answer (score 1):

Это уберет строку состояния для Activity

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

Это уберет строчку состояния , но чтобы заголовок остался

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Comment: Я бы не хотел убирать. Хочется сделать прозрачным.

Comment: Тогда точно попробуй атрибут в стиль '<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>' но там начинается с API 19

Comment: Пробовал. Полупрозрачный получается. Полной прозрачности добиться не смог.